# leave optional parameters out conditionally

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider this function:

```
def foo(x, y=1):
  return x*x + y*y
```

now I want to call foo like this:

```
if param_y == None:
  z = foo(3)
else:
  z=foo(3,param_y)
```

Where param_y is determined somewhere before. I want to simplify this, such that there is only one foo-call in the code, especially since if I have multiple of such optional parameters, I'd get an enormous (and ugly!!) if-else clause, so I can do:

```
z = foo(3, param_y if param_y != None else 1)
```

But this requires the caller to know that 1 is the default value of y, which I find a bit ugly as well. Is there an alternative syntax for this, like:

```
z =  foo(3, if param_y != None: param_y)
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't you update the foo function?

```
def foo(x, y):
    if y is None:
        y = 1
    return x*x + y*y
```

and call everytime :

```
z=foo(3,param_y)
```

Comment: Consider that the foo-function is from a library.

Comment: @Herbert, create a wrapper around it.

Comment: @pavel_form: sure, but not ideal ;) wrappers are very verbose and boilerplate.

Comment: They are verbose, but they allow to have the same behavior for every call so you don't have to add the same tests everywhere you use this function.